# Would escaping "\" standard English characters create any unwanted results?

Tags: php, escaping

While I'm sure it is overkill and likely leads to some performance issues, are there any other possible issues one would face if they had accidentally escaped a standard English alphanumeric character in a string in PHP?

Example:

```
$name = "Stack\Overflow";
```

Comment: If you're using double quotes, then yes. There are multiple combinations that will replace your text with control characters, example: `\n` = new line, `\t` = tab etc. So the text `"This will give you a \new line"` will actually replace `\n` with a new line instead. Who did "accidentally" escape the text?

Comment: Perhaps referring to the [control sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) list would be helpful...

Comment: @SamOnela - I was looking for that page! :)